# What child elements are valid inside HTML5 <small>?

Tags: html

I'm adding a few short paragraphs of terms and conditions text above a contact form, which seems logical to put inside a `small` element. Is it valid to add child `p` elements inside a `small` though? All examples tend to have it the other way round...

Thanks.

Comment: Well, have you [looked at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small)?

Comment: can't see anything about child element in the documentation, can you point it out?

Comment: Yes. As I say, the example has `small` inside `p`. It states permitted content as *phrasing content*- which doesn't seem to include `p` but I'm not sure- hence my question

Comment: @MattiaNocerino "permitted content".

Comment: @Inigo `p` is a block element, so it's not valid to use it inside `small`. You can always check you markup via the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: [Paragraphs are block-level elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small), only [`phrasing content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) are permitted content of `small`.

So, as `p` is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), it's not valid for it to be a child of `small`.

You can always check your markup via the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/).